# Quill - INSERT INTO SELECT... syntax?

Tags: mysql, scala, quill

So I recently moved over from ScalikeJDBC to Quill in my scala project due to the async support.

Is there any support for any SQL syntax like the below examples?

```
INSERT INTO People (id, cityID)
SELECT 52, Cities.id
FROM Cities
WHERE Cities.name = 'New York City';

INSERT INTO State (id, numCities)
SELECT 4, COUNT(*)
FROM  Cities
WHERE Cities.state = 'NY'
```

#### Expected behavior

I'd try things like

```
quote {
   for {
      count <- query[City].filter(_.state == 'NY').size
   } yield query[State].insert(lift(State(4, count))
}

quote {
   query[City].filter(_.state == 'NY').size.nested.insert(count => lift(State(4, count))
}
```

But it gives errors like:

- "value map is not a member of Long" regarding ".size"
- "nested is not a member of Long" regarding ".size"

Of course if I do something like below I get a bunch of errors:

```
quote {
   for {
      count <- List(query[City].filter(_.state == 'NY').size)
   } yield query[State].insert(lift(State(4, count))
}
```

#### Workaround

Currently the only workaround seems to be running two separate queries (one for getting the count and the 2nd for inserting). However I'd think that this would get inefficient if I was doing a lot of select based inserts.

#### With Raw Queries

I've tried alternatives using infix such as:

```
quote {
    infix"""
      INSERT INTO Languages (id,iso639_1,name)
      VALUES (
        (SELECT x2.id + 1
        FROM (SELECT id FROM Languages UNION SELECT 0) x2
        LEFT JOIN Languages x1 ON (x2.id + 1) = x1.id
        WHERE x1.id IS NULL LIMIT 1),
        'Hello',
        'World'
      );
    """.as[?]
}
```

But it keeps on giving these errors:

```
[error] (run-main-4a) com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.exceptions.MySQLException: Error 1064 - #42000 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Languages (id,iso639_1,name)
[error]       VALUES (
[error]         (SELECT x2.id ' at line 2
[error] com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.exceptions.MySQLException: Error 1064 - #42000 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Languages (id,iso639_1,name)
[error]       VALUES (
[error]         (SELECT x2.id ' at line 2
```

Which is not true since I copy pasted the raw SQL into a sql browser and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
  final case class TestTable(id: Long, name: String)

  final val ctx = new SqlMirrorContext(MirrorSqlDialect, Literal)

  import ctx._

  final val table  = quote(query[TestTable])
  final val size   = quote(table.filter(_.name == "hello world").size)
  //the insert action
  final val insert = quote {
    (e: TestTable) => table.insert(e)
  }
```

// test

```
//INSERT INTO TestTable (id,name) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable x1 WHERE x1.name = 'hello world'), '')
ctx.run(insert(TestTable(size, "")))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks this was really helpful. Can you also enlighten me on the first example? How would you resolve the query to a single value like count? Thanks

Comment: i have not good idea for this case `insert into ... SELECT 52, Cities.id ...`;i think using `infix"<SQL>".as[Insert[TestTable]]"` is feasible ; are your miss `as[Insert[Table]]`?